# How to interchange a fixed string with sequential string in R?

Tags: r, rep

How do I interchange a fixed string with a sequential string?

For instance, if I want to repeat a pattern of a string, I would do the following:

```
> rep(c("Filler","Model"),2)
[1] "Filler" "Model"  "Filler" "Model"  "Filler" "Model"
```

But, I want something like this where I can automatically add numbers behind "Model" with each iteration of a repeat:

```
[1] "Filler" "Model 1" "Filler" "Model 2" "Filler" "Model 3"
```

Is there a way to combine `rep()` with `sprintf()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one base R approach.  We can access all even elements of the input vector and then paste with a numeric sequence.

```r
x <- rep(c("Filler","Model"),3)
x[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- paste(x[c(FALSE, TRUE)], c(1:3))
x

[1] "Filler" "Model 1" "Filler" "Model 2" "Filler" "Model 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative:

```
x <- rep(c("Filler","Model"),3)

x[x=="Model"] = paste("Model", seq_along(x[x=="Model"]))
x
```

```
[1] "Filler"  "Model 1" "Filler"  "Model 2" "Filler"  "Model 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option if the Filler Model sequence is not always alternating:

```r
x <- c("Filler", "Model", "Filler", "Model", "Model", "Model")

replace(x, which(x == "Model"), paste(x, cumsum(x == "Model"))[which(x == "Model")])
#> [1] "Filler"  "Model 1" "Filler"  "Model 2" "Model 3" "Model 4"
```

Or slightly more compact

```r
paste(x, replace(cumsum(x == "Model"), which(x!="Model"), ""))
#> [1] "Filler " "Model 1" "Filler " "Model 2" "Model 3" "Model 4"
```